# Изменение поля при вставке и обновлении

Tags: sql-server

Надо, чтобы при вставке и обновлении записи в таблице, обновлялось поле `DateUpdate`. Написал вот такой триггер:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[SomeTableInsertUpdate]
ON [dbo].[SomeTable]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE (DateUpdate)
        RETURN
    UPDATE [SomeTable] SET
        DateUpdate = SYSDATETIME()
    FROM inserted I
    WHERE I.ID = [SomeTable].ID
END
```

На обновление все прекрасно работает, а вот на вставку не хочет. Подскажите, в чем ошибка? Делаю на `MS SQL Server 2008`. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот эта строка

```
IF UPDATE (DateUpdate)
```

для вставки оператором `INSERT` всегда вернет `TRUE`.

Если вы этим условием хотите отрезать повторный вызов триггера на update в его теле, то проще всего сделать это либо полным запретом в свойствах сервера, либо провериться на уровень вызова:

```
IF ( (SELECT trigger_nestlevel(OBJECT_ID('SomeTable')) ) > 1 )
  RETURN
```

Comment: Благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

Причину уже озвучили. Еще один вариант решения - добавить для поля `DateUpdate` значение по-умолчанию, которое и будет заполнять поле при вставке.